# Getting values printed from dictionary without being repeated?

Tags: python

I am trying to match a random amount of employee records to an auditor. so I made a dictionary, the key being the name of the auditors and the values being the list of the employees' names. However, as the result of this, the dictionary values become cumulative and make duplicates of themselves as iteration for auditor's name(dictionary key) goes on. How can I eliminate the duplication of the values?? (audlst is the list of auditors and Empnamelst is the list of the employees and the amount of random employee records that will be assigned to the auditor is determined by user input as empunderaud, the values(employee names) are series taken from a dataframe)

Code:

```
    empunderaud=input('How many records will be assigned to each auditor?')
    empunderaud=int(empunderaud)
    print('Record successfully assigned to auditors')
    #take the emp names only from Mydf
    Empnamelst=Mydf.iloc[:,0] 
    #assign emps to audnames
    assigndict={}
    for audname in audlst:
            print("\nRecords assigned to",audname,': ' )
            rndemp=Empnamelst.sample(empunderaud)
            assigndict[audname]=rndemp

            print(assigndict.values())
```

result:

```
How many records will be assigned to each auditor?2
Record successfully assigned to auditors

Records assigned to ann : 
dict_values([302    Carr, Claudia  N
67      Gonzalez, Maria
Name: Employee_Name, dtype: object])

Records assigned to iron : 
dict_values([302    Carr, Claudia  N
67      Gonzalez, Maria
Name: Employee_Name, dtype: object, 49            Rogers, Ivan
87    Wallace, Courtney  E
Name: Employee_Name, dtype: object])

Records assigned to jin : 
dict_values([302    Carr, Claudia  N
67      Gonzalez, Maria
Name: Employee_Name, dtype: object, 49            Rogers, Ivan
87    Wallace, Courtney  E
Name: Employee_Name, dtype: object, 241         Wolk, Hang  T
235    Winthrop, Jordan  
Name: Employee_Name, dtype: object])
```

as you can see the employee names in the result are being cumulated how can make this not cumulative?

Comment: Perform the sample operation once, outside the loop. That will prevent duplicates. Then shuffle the sample and split it into subsamples, one for each auditor.

Comment: @BoarGules yes.. uh I don't get the "shuffle the sample & split it into samples" part. Can you guide me to a real short code if it doesn't bother you??

Comment: Look at module `random`. You probably want `random.shuffle()`.